# SQL Server: How to use UNION with two queries that BOTH have a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server, union, where-clause

**Given:**

Two queries that require filtering:

```
select top 2 t1.ID, t1.ReceivedDate
  from Table t1
 where t1.Type = 'TYPE_1'
 order by t1.ReceivedDate desc
```

And:

```
select top 2 t2.ID
  from Table t2
 where t2.Type = 'TYPE_2'
 order by t2.ReceivedDate desc
```

Separately, these return the `ID`s I'm looking for: (13, 11 and 12, 6)

Basically, I want the two most recent records for two specific types of data.

I want to union these two queries together like so:

```
select top 2 t1.ID, t2.ReceivedDate
  from Table t1
 where t1.Type = 'TYPE_1'
 order by ReceivedDate desc
union
select top 2 t2.ID
  from Table t2
 where t2.Type = 'TYPE_2'
 order by ReceivedDate desc
```

**Problem:**

The problem is that this query is invalid because the first `select` cannot have an `order by` clause if it is being `unioned`. And it cannot have `top 2` without having `order by`.

How can I fix this situation?

Comment: I guess you mean that you have trouble with the `order by` not `where`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should be able to alias them and use as subqueries (part of the reason your first effort was invalid was because the first select had two columns (ID and ReceivedDate) but your second only had one (ID) - also, Type is a reserved word in SQL Server, and can't be used as you had it as a column name):

```
declare @Tbl1 table(ID int, ReceivedDate datetime, ItemType Varchar(10))
declare @Tbl2 table(ID int, ReceivedDate datetime, ItemType Varchar(10))

insert into @Tbl1 values(1, '20010101', 'Type_1')
insert into @Tbl1 values(2, '20010102', 'Type_1')
insert into @Tbl1 values(3, '20010103', 'Type_3')

insert into @Tbl2 values(10, '20010101', 'Type_2')
insert into @Tbl2 values(20, '20010102', 'Type_3')
insert into @Tbl2 values(30, '20010103', 'Type_2')

SELECT a.ID, a.ReceivedDate FROM
 (select top 2 t1.ID, t1.ReceivedDate
  from @tbl1 t1
  where t1.ItemType = 'TYPE_1'
  order by ReceivedDate desc
 ) a
union
SELECT b.ID, b.ReceivedDate FROM
 (select top 2 t2.ID, t2.ReceivedDate
  from @tbl2 t2
  where t2.ItemType = 'TYPE_2'
  order by t2.ReceivedDate desc
 ) b
```

Answer (score 10):

```
select * from 
(
    select top 2 t1.ID, t1.ReceivedDate
    from Table t1
    where t1.Type = 'TYPE_1'
    order by t1.ReceivedDate de
) t1
union
select * from 
(
    select top 2 t2.ID
    from Table t2
    where t2.Type = 'TYPE_2'
    order by t2.ReceivedDate desc
) t2
```

or using CTE (SQL Server 2005+)

```
;with One as
(
    select top 2 t1.ID, t1.ReceivedDate
    from Table t1
    where t1.Type = 'TYPE_1'
    order by t1.ReceivedDate de
)
,Two as
(
    select top 2 t2.ID
    from Table t2
    where t2.Type = 'TYPE_2'
    order by t2.ReceivedDate desc
)
select * from One
union
select * from Two
```

Comment: This is the best answer, especially using the CTE. Just on a point of style, Microsoft recommend ending _all_ SQL statements with a semicolon, and will require it in a future version. If you end all of your statements with a semicolon, you never need to fake it by preceding the `WITH` with one.

Answer (score 6):

```
declare @T1 table(ID int, ReceivedDate datetime, [type] varchar(10))
declare @T2 table(ID int, ReceivedDate datetime, [type] varchar(10))

insert into @T1 values(1, '20010101', '1')
insert into @T1 values(2, '20010102', '1')
insert into @T1 values(3, '20010103', '1')

insert into @T2 values(10, '20010101', '2')
insert into @T2 values(20, '20010102', '2')
insert into @T2 values(30, '20010103', '2')

;with cte1 as
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(order by ReceivedDate desc) as rn
  from @T1
  where [type] = '1'
),
cte2 as
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(order by ReceivedDate desc) as rn
  from @T2
  where [type] = '2'
)
select *
from cte1
where rn <= 2
union all
select *
from cte2
where rn <= 2
```

Answer (score 4):

The basic premise of the question and the answers are wrong. Every Select in a union can have a where clause. It's the ORDER BY in the first query that's giving yo the error.

Comment: So my comment = 15 characters, but THIS is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is misleading because it attempts to fix a problem that is not a problem.   You actually CAN have a WHERE CLAUSE in each segment of a UNION.  You cannot have an ORDER BY except in the last segment.   Therefore, this should work...

```
select top 2 t1.ID, t1.ReceivedDate
from Table t1
where t1.Type = 'TYPE_1'
-----remove this-- order by ReceivedDate desc
union
select top 2 t2.ID,  t2.ReceivedDate --- add second column
  from Table t2
 where t2.Type = 'TYPE_2'
order by ReceivedDate desc
```

Comment: The `TOP 2` in the first query requires the first `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

Create views on two first "selects" and "union" them.

Comment: -1 Creating two views just in order to select and union them seems wrong.

Comment: +1 because this answer is technically correct, but its not the best solution.

Comment: @Ken White Do you really think it's a good idea to vote down answers just because they are not the best solution? It's technically correct solution given in 30 seconds and with no code involved. @DJTripleThreat: Thank you for your professional attitude.

Comment: Yes, I do. The whole point of this site is to find the best answers to questions, and to provide the best answers you can to other's questions. The reputation system rewards people for giving correct (and well thought out) answers, and people who give quick, poorly conceived or wrong answers lose reputation. "Technically correct" isn't always appropriate (or right). I could say that the solution was to print out each querie's result and put them together with scissors and paste - while "technically correct", because it would work, would you vote for that answer?

Comment: Its my opinion that if the answer has the desired outcome, it shouldn't be downvoted. However, not every correct answer should be upvoted if its not useful. Pavel was also the first to respond so I usually upvote any correct answers that I get within the first hour I post.

Thats just me though.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.
you are selecting

> t1.ID, t2.ReceivedDate
>     from Table t1

union

> t2.ID
>     from Table t2

which is incorrect.

so you have to write

> t1.ID, t1.ReceivedDate from Table t1 
>   union
>   t2.ID, t2.ReceivedDate from Table t1

you can use sub query here

```
 SELECT tbl1.ID, tbl1.ReceivedDate FROM
      (select top 2 t1.ID, t1.ReceivedDate
      from tbl1 t1
      where t1.ItemType = 'TYPE_1'
      order by ReceivedDate desc
      ) tbl1 
 union
    SELECT tbl2.ID, tbl2.ReceivedDate FROM
     (select top 2 t2.ID, t2.ReceivedDate
      from tbl2 t2
      where t2.ItemType = 'TYPE_2'
      order by t2.ReceivedDate desc
     ) tbl2
```

so it will return only distinct values by default from both table.

Answer (score 0):

select top 2 t1.ID, t2.ReceivedDate, 1 SortBy
from Table t1
where t1.Type = 'TYPE_1'
union
select top 2 t2.ID, 2 SortBy
from Table t2
where t2.Type = 'TYPE_2'
order by 3,2