# Combine 2 SQL columns into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine values from two columns into one, but I want them to be one underneath the other when I export to Excel.

Example:

```
Select 'TEST' + ' ' + 'TEST2'
```

this returns

```
TEST   TEST2
```

But I want the output to be:

```
TEST
TEST2
```

I have two columns: Data1 Varchar (35), NULL. Data2 Varchar (35), NULL

I appreciate your help..

Comment: Hint: [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: How to use UNION with two queries that BOTH have a WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426767/sql-server-how-to-use-union-with-two-queries-that-both-have-a-where-clause)

Comment: Please edit your question, provide columns and their data types

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Select 'test'
union 
Select 'test2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate and insert CHAR(13) where you want the line break. Ex.:

```
PRINT 'Line1' + CHAR(13) + 'Line2'
```

Prints:

`Line1
Line2`

Comment: I am trying use this in my query and as you know print is not allowed to be in one of the columns. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I thought you wanted a _message_ output. In this case, the answer @Frivolin gave would be the one

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for:

```
Select 'TEST' + char(13) + 'TEST2'
```

in grid output looks like it is one line but actually you get two lines if you copy paste

EDIT, as suggested in another answer:

```
Select 'TEST' + char(13)+char(10) + 'TEST2'
```

EDIT (based on new info on question):

```
select isnull(column1, '') + char(13) + char(10) + isnull(column2, '')
from YourTable
```

Comment: PawelCz. The output still TEST TEST2 and I want to be:

Comment: TEST and Test2 underneath it

Comment: copy paste output to notepad, it is underneath

Comment: Even in notepad still getting one line. Thanks1

Comment: try edited, I have tested previous version and worked fine

Comment: No, That is in one line as well

Comment: something is wrong with your data, see my comment on the question

Comment: I added data types

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNION ALL as @dmitry Bychenko gave and in Excel when you export it, you can merge the 2 cells into one cell.

There isn't a way for SQL to convert two row output and make sure they are in one cell in Excel. This is something you would have to "merge" on your own.

Answer (score 0):

char(13) is CR. For DOS-/Windows-style CRLF , you should use char(13)+char(10):

```
Select 'TEST' + char(13)+char(10) + 'TEST2'
```

Comment: This gives one line even when I copy it.